# How do I use power query to import a csv file and selectively map different values to different columns in Excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I currently have a CSV file that I import into excel, example under Source Data. The issue is that 90% of the data has 5 values, but some have 6. So when I import the data using the below PowerQuery, the first value is mapped to **Quantity**, then the next is **Brand**, **Type**, **Number** and **Name**.

The issue is the last row has 6 entries and I need to have *'1'* mapped to **Quantity** ,*'AK Interactive'* mapped to **Name**,*'3rd Generation 17ml'* mapped to **Type**,*'AK11001'* mapped to **Number** and *'White'* mapped to **Name**

I am guessing there should be a way to say if value 2 is *'AK Interactive'* and value 4 is '3rd Generation 17ml' then map the columns differently in Power Query some how .

### Source Data

My colors

Mar 11, 2024 at 10:35:52 PM

1, Ammo, Acrylics, A.MIG-250, Night Blue Grey

1, Games Workshop, Air 12ml, Averland Sunset, Averland Sunset

1, Tamiya, Glossy Acrylic 10 ml, X-22, Clear

1, AK Interactive, Weathering Specials, AK088, Worn Effects Acrylic Fluid

1, AK Interactive, Acrylics, 3rd Generation 17ml, AK11001, White

### Example of What it should look like in Excel

| Quantity | Brand | Type | Number | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ammo | Acrylics | A.MIG-250 | Night Blue Grey |
| 1 | Games Workshop | Air 12ml | Averland Sunset | Averland Sunset |
| 1 | Tamiya | Glossy Acrylic 10 ml | X-22 | Clear |
| 1 | AK Interactive | Weathering Specials | AK088 | Worn Effects Acrylic Fluid |
| 1 | AK Interactive | 3rd Generation 17ml | AK11001 | White |

### Power Query Code I have now

```
let
Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\JustinFo\Downloads\Paint.txt"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=5, Encoding=65001, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
#"Change Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}}),
#"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Change Type",4),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Top Rows",{{"Column1", "Quantity"}, {"Column2", "Brand"}, {"Column3", "Type"}, {"Column4", "Number"}, {"Column5", "Name"}}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Brand", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Quantity", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Brand", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Type", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Number", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Name", Text.Trim, type text}}),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Trimmed Text"," 12ml","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Type"}),
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value"," 18ml","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Type"}),
#"Replaced Value2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value1"," 17ml","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Type"}),
#"Replaced Value3" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Replaced Value2"," (DevlanMud)","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Number"}) in #"Replaced Value3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Table.TransformRows` function to do that after you have imported the table

I show two variations below

- As you describe in your question where you look at the absolute values of the 2nd and 4th columns
- Another variations where you just check the contents of the sixth column

You will need to import all 6 columns in order to have all the data though.

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\ron\Desktop\test.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=6, Encoding=1252]),
        colNames=Table.ColumnNames(Source),

//since your delimiter is really <comma><space>, need to trim all the entries
    trimAll = Table.TransformColumns(Source, List.Transform(colNames, each {_, Text.Trim})),
    
    x = List.Zip({List.RemoveLastN(colNames,1),{"Quantity", "Brand", "Type", "Number", "Name"}}),
    #"Rename Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(trimAll, x),

//Pick one of the transform rows options and delete the other

//If six entries, remove 3rd
    #"Transform Rows" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"Rename Columns", (r)=>
            Record.TransformFields(r,{
                {"Type", each if r[Column6]<>"" then r[Number] else _},
                {"Number", each if r[Column6]<>"" then r[Name] else _},
                {"Name", each if r[Column6]<>"" then r[Column6] else _}
            }))),

// 2nd option looking at absolute values for Brand and Number columns
    #"Transform Rows2" = Table.FromRecords(Table.TransformRows(#"Rename Columns", (r)=>
            Record.TransformFields(r,{
                {"Type", each if r[Brand]="AK Interactive" and r[Number]="3rd Generation 17ml" then r[Number] else _},
                {"Number", each if r[Brand]="AK Interactive" and r[Number]="3rd Generation 17ml" then r[Name] else _},
                {"Name", each if r[Brand]="AK Interactive" and r[Number]="3rd Generation 17ml" then r[Column6] else _}
            }))),



    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Transform Rows",{"Column6"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

***CSV File***

```
1, Ammo, Acrylics, A.MIG-250, Night Blue Grey
1, Games Workshop, Air 12ml, Averland Sunset, Averland Sunset
1, Tamiya, Glossy Acrylic 10 ml, X-22, Clear
1, AK Interactive, Weathering Specials, AK088, Worn Effects Acrylic Fluid
1, AK Interactive, Acrylics, 3rd Generation 17ml, AK11001, White
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me , I used the first option, but its good to see the second one as if I have to be specific for one thing then I can do this as well